# EF: .Distinct() and .GroupBy are undoing my filtering

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a very simple entity hierarchy in Entity Framework:

```
-Order
   -Customer
       - Name
   -ProductOrder
       - Quantity
       - Product
           - Name
           - Price
```

And I would like to write a query to get the TOP 5 customers that did the more expensive orders.

This query gives me the IDs of such customers: `[10, 10, 3, 3, 2]`

```
context
  .Orders  
  .Select(o => new { CustomerId = o.CustomerId, Value = o.Products.Sum(p => p.Quantity * p.Product.Price) })  
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
  .Select(x=> x.CustomerId)
  .Take(5)
  .ToArray()
  ;
```

Right, there are some customers that appears duplicated, because placed several big orders.

So I tried to add `.Distinct()` to avoid the duplicates, but I got : `[1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]`

```
context
  .Orders
  .Select(o => new { CustomerId = o.CustomerId, Value = o.Products.Sum(p => p.Quantity * p.Product.Price) })
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
  .Select(x=> x.CustomerId)
  .Distinct()
  .Take(5)
  .ToArray()
  ;
```

Rendering all the previous query useless. The same happens with `.GroupBy`.

How can I do that query with Entity Framework?

Comment: If one customer placed a single order for $10, and another customer placed 11 orders of $1 each, which customer should be listed first?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to group orders by customer_then_ find the top 5 customers?  As it stands you're looking for the top 5 orders.

Comment: @DStanley you are right. What I want is the customers with the top 5 biggest orders. I corrected the post.

Comment: Your response to my comment directly contradicts your response to @DStanley's comment.

Comment: @phoog the one with a single order of $10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want the customers with the top 5 biggest orders, but without repeating any customer more than once.  What you really want, therefore, is the top five customers by biggest order.  Here's one approach:

```
context
  .Orders  
  .Select(o => new { Customer = o.Customer, Value = o.Products.Sum(p => p.Quantity * p.Product.Price) }) 
  .GroupBy(o => x.Customer)
  .Select(o => new { Customer = o.Key, MaxValue = o.Select(a => a.Value).Max() })
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.MaxValue)
  .Select(x => x.Customer)
  .Take(5)
  .ToArray()
  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouping items or getting the distinct set of items is an operation that doesn't maintain ordering.  You'll need to filter out the items that you don't want *before* you order the data so that the ordering you apply can stick.

Comment: So what should be the way of doing that query?

Comment: @vtortola Exactly the way you'd have done it before, you just move the `GroupBy` so that it's above the order by.

Answer (score -3):

a `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` right before the `.Distinct()` should do the trick!

Comment: You're suggesting to pull ALL results form the database just to end up with 5 distinct rows?